# Email address with personal domain does not receive emails from forms on that domain

Tags: php, wordpress, email, url

Using either a custom built form, or a plugin for WordPress, I am not able to receive emails to ANY email with the same domain.

**Example 1:**

test@gilipe.com is the email used to receive submissions, the URL being gilipe.com, and the email won't make it through. Now, if I go in and replace the email with test@gmail.ca, the submission will go through without a hitch and I'll receive the email at test@gmail.ca

**Example 2:**

```
gilipe.com -> submit to test@gilipe.com -> FAIL
gilipe.com -> submit to gilipe@gmail.com -> PASS
```

It should be noted that gilipe.com is not a real domain, and that GoDaddy was used for the URL registration.

Comment: Check your "spam" or "bulk mail" folder

Comment: Perhaps the mails are delivered locally (ie. `/var/mail/$user`).

Comment: Oleg Dubas, I should have mentioned that you may assume I've gone through the easy steps first (checking spam, checking spelling 10 times, etc.)

Can you elaborate Carpetsmoker?

Comment: Is that domain setup to receive incoming emails? What are your MX records? Is it *only* email originating from your wordpress site that is not being  received?

Comment: Well, through a form on the site, if I used a gmail email, they get sent and received. Do I have to do anything special for emails with the same domain?
Emails with the same domain can still receive emails normally from other sources, just no from a form on a site with the same domain.

And it's email from either WordPress or a static form (a part of the site doesn't use WP at all, I've tested there as well, no dice).

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with GoDaddy. This happens every time we setup an account that has the MX records pointed away from the host, yet the host is still catching those e-mails locally without checking the MX records. In other words, it's most likely a server configuration problem.

If you're using Plesk or CPanel, there should be an option to turn off local e-mail delivery. Otherwise I recommend you contact digital-ocean (the hosting company you originally tagged) and ask them to sort it out.